# How to fix this problem？I couldn't find the firefox logo in my vmware's ubuntu 20.04, and I tried deleting it and reinstalling, but it didn't work

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9xTb.jpg)

How to fix this problem？I couldn't find the firefox logo in my vmware's ubuntu 20.04, and I tried deleting it and reinstalling, but it didn't work. When I wrote some prompts in the terminal, it gave the answers just like what in the picture.
can you offer me some advice?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.